# looking for a good resource for studying parametric equations

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I am relatively proficient in most material found in high school math courses but one of my weaknesses is in parametric equations and expressions; I really struggle to understand and apply them.  Does anyone know of a good book or online resource written by an expert that really introduces and explains them step-by-step from the very basics?  Thanks in advance.